# open a form clicking href to update respected id data

Tags: php, jquery, html

In my app I have a user record table with order and edit button.I want when I click edit button a new form open just below that row and fetch data for that user in that form.I pass that userid using href.
This is my user record table code

```
<div class="panel-body">
      <div class="dataTable_wrapper">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
          <thead>
            <tr>                                           
              <th>Candidate</th>
              <th>Gender</th>
              <th>Date of Birth</th>
              <th>Gotra</th>
              <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

            <?php
            $result=mysqli_query($conn,"select candidateid,candidatename,gender,dob,gotra from candidateinfo where clientid='$clientid' ");
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
              {
                echo "<tr class='odd gradeX'>";
                echo "<td>" .  $row[1] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" .  $row[2] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" .  $row[3] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" .  $row[4] . "</td>";
                echo "<td><a data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' title='Order' href=reorders.php?vcandidateid=" . urlencode(base64_encode("$row[0]")) . ">Order</a>";
                echo " || <a data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' title='Edit' href=candidateedit.php?vcandidateid=" . urlencode(base64_encode("$row[0]")) . ">Edit</a></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
              }
            ?>                      
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I retrieve data from database in this table.Please help me.

> jquery and form

```
 <script>
 $(function() {
   $('#edit').click(function() {
       $('#update_form').show();
     });        
    });
   </script>

    <form id="update_form" class="form-horizontal" action="candidatedb.php" method="post">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="hidden-xs col-sm-4 control-label" for="candidateName"><small class="color-red vlarge-text">*</small>Candidate Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8 xs-padding-l-r-none">
          <input type="text" id="candidatename" name="candidatename">
          <span class="help-block errmsg margin-none"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <div class="form-group">
          <button class="col-sm-2 btn btnDark" id="Submit" type="submit" value="" >Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: I don't see any code yhat opens a form and fill it with data. Did you tried to do that so far ?

Comment: no...I don't understand how to do that.

Comment: you'll need `AJAX` in order to do that without refreshing the page.

Comment: yes....but how i use that?I know how I open that form using jquery but I don't know how i retrieve data in that form with this id

Comment: please show me some example

Comment: you said that you know how to open a form with `jQuery`, try some code that do that task and edit your question bby adding the code you meant to write and I'll be here for further help. StackOverflow isn't meant to do others business, at least try out and we will help you.

Comment: see my updated code